# Crystal Reports for VS 2010 - OLE Object Graphic Location Editor is Rounding DB Values

Tags: google-maps, crystal-reports, rounding-error

Background:

I am using Crystal Reports to generate a Work Order styled sheet which displays a Google Map image with a marker indicating the service location. The GPS coordinates are stored in an access database as "Long" variables which have 13 decimal places.

I display the Google Map image in an OLE Object and set the Graphic Location URL to a static Google Map web page. I pass the values from the Connected database to the URL String:

```
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" & {DbTblName.gps_lat} & "," & {DbTblName.gps_long} & "&zoom=15&size=256x256&markers=color:red%7C" & {DbTblName.gps_lat} & "," & {DbTblName.gps_long};
```

Where `DbTblName.gps_lat` and `DbTblName.gps_long` are the GPS coordinates pulled from the database based on the `Select Command` used to populate the report.

The Issue:

Crystal Reports is rounding the value of `DbTblName.gps_lat` and `DbTblName.gps_long` to 2 decimal places; which is causing the marker on the Google image to be off by 100's of meters.

What I've Tried:

- Adjusted the Number Format of the GPS Coordinates field on the Crystal Report to the Maximum number of visible decimal places as well as the maximum number of decimal place rounding. 
  *NOTE: This creates a custom number format; and the decimal places appear in the report fields but the format change does not get translated to the Graphic Location URL String*
- Change the System Default Settings of Number Format to accept the maximum number of decimal places (both visible and rounding).
- Change the datatype in the access database to "Short Text" and pass the coordinates as Strings. 
  *NOTE: This actually worked fine, it put the markers in the correct spot, and would be quickest solution; but it is not the solution I want. I suppose in the worst case scenario I could create One Database Field as "Long" and One as "Short Text" but it seems silly to duplicate the values in the database. I need the Access database to keep GPS stored as "Long" to perform searches based on GPS Location.*

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Report is accessed through website using ASP.NET 4.0 Framework (C# code-behind) and is viewed by user in PDF Format.